# vsc python debugger and pylance doesn't recognize installed package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I installed `snowflake-connector-python` in my virtual environment recently using `pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]==2.7.6`, and it works ok when I run my script from the command line with the virtual environment activated. I set the same virtual environment as VSC interpreter, but trying to run python debugger raises an exeception:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'
```

I also can see that `pylance` doesn't recognize the package either, but all other installed packages are recognized with no problem.

I have seen several questions and answers for similar cases, but none of them have worked for me.

**EDIT**

I added the parameter `python` to the *launch.json*:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "python": "${workspaceFolder}/MyVenv/Scripts/python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "--env", "dev",
                "--argument"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        }
    ]
}
```

Getting the same result.

**EDIT**

I found that the way the module is imported makes `pylance` to recognize it, but debugger is still raising the error.

This is the old and new way of importing the module into the code:

Old way

[image]

New way

[image]

With the new way, code is not highlighted by `pylance`, but it is not colored as recognized, though.

Comment: Did you tried restarting vscode? (if you have multiple windows open you have to close them all)

Comment: @Grekkq Yes I did, and I also restarted the computer

Comment: I am not using VSCode, hence only posting as a comment (impossible for me to reproduce...). When I want to use the IDLE Python IDE, I open a Windows console, use `activate` to install the required environment and launch IDLE with `python -m idlelib`. You should try to launch VSCode the same, meaning from a command line shell where you have previously activated the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally solved by doing this:

1. Delete the python virtual environment.
2. Create the python virtual environment again.
3. Activate the new python virtual enviroment.
4. Installing all libraries again with `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when your module can't be found, your environment hasn't been activated.

You can try adding the following code to your settings.json after choosing the python interpreter:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: @HuLuViCa `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}` Try adding the code to your launch.json and restart vscode.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: I can say that my environment is active since all the other modules installed are perfectly recognized by python debugger and pylance

Comment: Very strange, in my conda environment both running and debug work, have you tried using another conda environment? Or use conda command to install the package instead of pip

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VSCode as well. What I did is uninstalled the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, reinstalled it and then installed [Create Blank Python Module](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gnramsay.create-python-module) extension (all from Visual Studio Marketplace, of course)

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: @HuLuViCa I don't know what else could be wrong.. It might be a comatibility issue with the module or something

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on mac, it was caused by the interpreter in the vs code Python settings being set to the string "python" instead of the string "python3" (on my system running "python" gives an unknown command error)